# Is that a valid AVL-Tree insertion function?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I followed what my teacher said and it seems to work, but something looks wierd here ..

First of all, this is the class that should insert a new element to the AVL-Tree.

```
public class AVLTree<T> {
    private AVLTreeNode<T> root;

    public void insert(TreeElem<T> data) {
        if(root == null) 
            root = new AVLTreeNode<>(data, 0, null, null);
            else 
                insert(root, data, 0);
    }


    private void insert(AVLTreeNode<T> root, TreeElem<T> x, int height) {
//      root.setHeight(Math.max(root.getRight().getHeight(), root.getLeft().getHeight()) + 1);
        if(x.lessThan(root.getElem())) {
            if(root.getLeft() == null) {
                root.setLeft(new AVLTreeNode<>(x, height, null, null));
                if(Math.abs(root.getLeft().getHeight() - (root.getRight() == null ? 0 : root.getRight().getHeight())) == 2) 
                    if(x.lessThan(root.getLeft().getElem()))
                        rotateLeft(root);
                    else
                        doubleLeftRotate(root);
            } else 
                insert(root.getLeft(), x, height + 1);
        } else if(x.greaterThan(root.getElem())) {
            if(root.getRight() == null)  {
                root.setRight(new AVLTreeNode<>(x, height, null, null));
                if(Math.abs((root.getLeft() == null ? 0 : root.getLeft().getHeight()) - root.getRight().getHeight()) == 2)
                    if(x.lessThan(root.getLeft().getElem()))
                        rotateRight(root);
                    else
                        doubleRightRotate(root);
            } else 
                insert(root.getRight(), x, height + 1);
        }

        System.out.println((root.getRight() == null ? 0 : root.getRight().getHeight()) - (root.getLeft() == null ? 0 : root.getLeft().getHeight()));
    }


    public void print() {
        print(root);
    }

    private void print(AVLTreeNode<T> root) {
        if(root == null) return;
        System.out.println(root.getElem().toString());
        print(root.getLeft());
        print(root.getRight());
    }

    /***************************************
     ************ ROTATIONS ****************
     ***************************************/

    private void rotateLeft(AVLTreeNode<T> node) {
        // Swap node with node.left
        AVLTreeNode<T> temp = node, right = temp.getRight();
        // 
        node.setElem(right.getElem());
        node.setHeight(right.getHeight());
        node.setLeft(right.getLeft());
        node.setRight(right.getRight());
        // set root
        right.setElem(temp.getElem());
        right.setHeight(temp.getHeight());
        right.setRight(temp.getRight());
        right.setLeft(temp.getLeft());
        // 
        node.setLeft(node.getRight());
        node.setRight(null);

    }

    private void rotateRight(AVLTreeNode<T> node) {
        // Swap node with node.left
        AVLTreeNode<T> temp = node, left = temp.getLeft();
        // 
        node.setElem(left.getElem());
        node.setHeight(left.getHeight());
        node.setLeft(left.getLeft());
        node.setRight(left.getRight());
        // set root
        left.setElem(temp.getElem());
        left.setHeight(temp.getHeight());
        left.setRight(temp.getRight());
        left.setLeft(temp.getLeft());
        // 
        node.setRight(node.getLeft());
        node.setLeft(null);
    }

    private void doubleLeftRotate(AVLTreeNode<T> node) {
        rotateRight(node.getRight());
        rotateLeft(node);
    }

    private void doubleRightRotate(AVLTreeNode<T> node) {
        rotateLeft(node.getLeft());
        rotateRight(node);
    }
}
```

According to my test class, it seems to work.

But I can't understand something here:

At:

```
                if(x.lessThan(root.getLeft().getElem()))
                    rotateLeft(root);
                else
                    doubleLeftRotate(root);
```

What should I check whether x is less than root.getLeft,

if I assigned the left side with x?

TreeElem is a comparable interface.

But the main point is:

my Insert method is good or not?

Comment: What do you mean by is it "good"? If you've tried it and you're getting the output you expect, I'd say it's good. If you want a thorough review of your code, you should repost this on [codereview.se].

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm asking if you can see any problems there

Comment: Is there a problem with the output? Is a particular test case not working?

Comment: StackOverflow is designed to help diagnose and solve observed problems, rather than to vet code "in case". I'd definitely recommend to move this to [codereview.se].